# How to make a roofs image for qemu using febootstrap

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, qemu

I tried to use febootstrap to make a roofs image for qemu-kvm.

I frist generated a roofs with command

```
febootstrap -i coreutils -i vim centos79 centos_7.9 https://mirrors.163.com/centos/7/os/x86_64/
```

After that, I got a directory as following

```
> tree centos_7.9/ -L 1
centos_7.9/
├── bin -> usr/bin
├── boot
├── dev
├── etc
├── home
├── lib -> usr/lib
├── lib64 -> usr/lib64
├── media
├── mnt
├── opt
├── proc
├── root
├── run
├── sbin -> usr/sbin
├── srv
├── sys
├── tmp
├── usr
└── var
```

Then, I created a qemu image and copied all file from centos_7.9 to the image.

```
qemu-img create centos79.img 1g
mkfs.ext4 centos79.img
mkdir mnt_dir
sudo mount -o loop centos79.img mnt_dir
cp centos_7.9/* mnt_dir
umount mnt_dir
```

However, when I run

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel /boot/vmlinuz-`uname -r` \
    -hda=centos79.img \
    -append "root=/dev/sda console=ttyS0" \
    -enable-kvm -nographic
```

or

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel /boot/vmlinuz-`uname -r` \
    -drive file=centos79.img \
    -append "root=/dev/hda console=ttyS0" \
    -enable-kvm -nographic
```

It reported that

```
[    1.766919] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[    1.767906] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.14.0-3.1.0.kwai+ #10
[    1.767906] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS 0.5.1 01/01/2011
[    1.767906] Call Trace:
[    1.767906]  dump_stack_lvl+0x34/0x48
[    1.767906]  panic+0xfb/0x2cd
[    1.767906]  mount_block_root+0x28c/0x29f
[    1.767906]  prepare_namespace+0x13b/0x16a
[    1.767906]  kernel_init_freeable+0x17f/0x1a4
[    1.767906]  ? rest_init+0xc0/0xc0
[    1.767906]  kernel_init+0x16/0x130
[    1.767906]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
[    1.767906] Kernel Offset: disabled
[    1.767906] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---
```

What should I do to fix this?